# phalcon model conditions across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, phalcon

I am new to phalcon and mvc so please bear with me.

I have two tables, media and users both with media and users models respectively. Code below

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;        
class Media extends Model
        {

            public $media_id, $user, $media_type, $title, $status_on, $visible, $modified_date;

            public function initialize()
            {
                $this->belongsTo('user', 'users', 'user_id');
            }
        }
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;        
class Users extends Model
    {
        public $user_id, $first_name, $last_name, $email_address, $status, $created_on;

        public function initialize()
        {
             $this->hasMany('user_id','media','user');
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve with the following condition

```
"title LIKE '%just a text%' AND status_on='P' AND media_type=4 AND status='A'";
```

This is done through a controller method to access the media model

```
$medium = media::find(array( "conditions" =>$conditions,
                "ORDER" => "modify_date DESC"));
```

I keep getting this error

```
Column 'status' doesn't belong to any of the selected models (1), when preparing: SELECT [Media].* FROM [Media] WHERE title LIKE '%just a text%' AND status_on='P' AND status='A'
```

Please can anyone help with this? I basically want to retrieve records based on conditions across the 2 tables which is usually written in the form of

```
SELECT * FROM media a, users b, WHERE a.user=b.user_id AND a.title LIKE '%just a text%' AND a.status_on='P' AND a.media_type=4 AND b.status='A'
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your question. What code is producing there error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the query builder to get the result you want: I created an example below that you may have to modify--i'm not sure if I got your join columns correct in the join method.

```
$media = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Media')
    ->join('Users', 'Media.media_id = Users.user_id', 'u')
    ->where("title LIKE '%just a text%'")
    ->andWhere("status_on='P'")
    ->andWhere("media_type=4")
    ->andWhere("u.status='A'")
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

For further instruction, please refer to the documentation: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#creating-queries-using-the-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achieved by utilising subqueries for filtering purposes.
This might not be the most elegant way but does the job.

```
Media::find([
    'conditions' => "title LIKE '%just a text%' AND status='A' AND user_id IN (SELECT user FROM [Media] WHERE [Users].user_id = user AND media_type=4)"
]);
```

Just keep in mind of square brackets and if your models have namespaces you should provide full path for example `[ACME\Models\Media].user_id`